# MongoDB exit automatically when first connected using java driver 2.3

Tags: java, mongodb

java code:

```
Mongo mongo = new Mongo(ip, dbPort);
DB db = mongo.getDB(dbName);
db.addUser(userName, password.toCharArray());
```

when I execute the first line of code `new Mongo(ip, dbPort)`, the mongo process exits automatically, and java code catches an exception `DBPort.findone failed`, but no problem occured using cmd to connect to the mongo.

os: windows 2003 sp2 x86
java driver: 2.3
jdk: 1.6